# cannot read property 'map' of undefined in React jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react by going through a react tutorial and i am getting a map undefind error. What should i do?
I am trying to iterate over the array to display the data of the array in the player component but i am still getting this error. i tried searching online and looking through at other map undefined error on stack overflow but none is like my problem that i am having.

```
const players = [
  {
    name: "Guil",
    score: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Treasure",
    score: 85
  },
  {
    name: "Ashley",
    score: 95
  },
  {
    name: "James",
    score: 80
  }

];

const Player = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="player">
      <span className="player-name">
        {props.name}
      </span>

      <Counter score={props.score} />
    </div>
  );
}

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <Header 
      title="Scoreboard"
      totalPlayers={4}
      />

      {/* Players list */}
      {props.initialPlayers.map(player =>
        <Player
        name={props.name} 
        score={props.score}
        />
        )}


    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App initialPlayers={ players}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on? The only issue I see in this current snippet is that `<Player name={props.name} score={props.score} />` should probably be `<Player name={player.name} score={player.score} />`

Comment: It is convenient to also copy the error message into the question as a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you didn't give us the error message, I can't be sure of what is actually undefined, although I doubt that `map` is undefined.

In the snippet below, you're trying to access `props.name` and `props.score`, which don't exist in the context. You've called the player `player` within the map callback and need to access it as such.

i.e. change `props.name` and `props.score` to `player.name` and `player.score`.

```
{props.initialPlayers.map(player =>
    <Player
        name={props.name} // player.name
        score={props.score} // player.score
    />
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cubrr's comment might have identify the issue that you are running into. You are probably getting the error here:

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="scoreboard">
      <Header 
      title="Scoreboard"
      totalPlayers={4}
      />

      {/* Players list */}
      {props.initialPlayers.map(player =>
        <Player
        name={props.name} 
        score={props.score}
        />
        )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

since props.name = undefined, you are trying to render something that does not exist. You will need to change it to:

```
{props.initialPlayers.map(player =>
  <Player
    name={player.name} 
    score={player.score}
  />
)}
```

Hope that helps.

React is relatively good at providing error logs for you, please be sure to take a look at error logs and it will tell you which line the error is occurring on.

Comment: I tried that and it didnt work and in the error logs it is saying the error is on line 61

Comment: Elisha, It would be best if you are able to send the snippet of the error. This will help debugging be easier.